# How come Microsoft products can be used on Android?

Tags: applications

I was under the impression that Microsoft software couldn't be run on Linux/OS X unless they emulated something or used a VM.

Thinking Android was Linux-based, I figured I wouldn't see any Microsoft products on Android, but about a month after owning my smartphone, I found out I could have apps like Outlook, One note, and etc.

Can anyone clarify this for me?

Comment: Yes, you as they don't want to loose people who own android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple: There are Android apps developed by Microsoft for the Android platform. Those apps have the same name like their counterpart on Windows and may have a similar functionality. But these are different programs that have explicitly developed for Android.

Therefore the answer to your question is: You can not use Microsoft software that has been developed on Android.

Answer (score 0):

## Microsoft chose to.

Microsoft created the android apps intentionally to get a higher userbase, like a sensible company. It ain't on Linux because Steve ballmer made MSOffice, and he called Linux 'A Cancer' Though that may change one day.

Also, **Android is NOT Linux** Its based on Linux. Yes, there is a difference.

-EDIT-

I would also like to point out you can get Google Apps on IOS, and vice-versa. It ain't new, either.